# How can i include a child horizontal linear layout in a parent vertical linear layout in android xml visualizer?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

In the image provided below the child horizontal layout(yellow) is covering only half of the screen and the other half is in maroon(parent vertical layout's colour).How can i make the horizontal layout cover the entire 2nd half?

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9Uk2.png)
    
     >

Comment: Can you please include the image mentioned, and your current code?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9Uk2.png   hi this is the image link.

Comment: Can you add that image into the original post, and a *text* version of your layout code, so others can reproduce your setup? Thanks!

Comment: your question is not clear, please try be more clear with your question

Comment: Change your *TextView*  `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` 
to `android:layout_height="match_parent" `

Comment: hi,i included my code into the original post. @JakeSteam

Comment: @anonymous there is no "wrap_content" part in my code

Comment: @TouhidulIslam hi added my code into the original post..please check it.Thanks

Comment: ok it's android:layout_height="0dp" so change it to `android:layout_height="match_parent"` otherwise change `android:layout_weight="0"` to `android:layout_weight="1"`

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want? your question isn't clear.
[image]

Comment: ...i tried this but still that problem persist,maybe there is some problem with my xml editor.

Comment: That might be the reason.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
            android:text="Demo Text" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/red">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/desiredone"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```